# MySQLi Query Not working if Primary Key have Serial Number Missing

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am Android developer and for use PHP API. I am working for make one query which update my table as requirement. This query is working fine if primary id have all number in serial like 1...2...3...4 etc. This is not working if there any number missing in it like 1...2...4... its updating till 1...2... but not working for row after serial number missing like this. In this case it is not working for row 4.

My Query is like below

```
$sql = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT _quid FROM tbl_quotes");
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
for ($x = 1; $x <= $num_rows; $x++) {
    $randomnumbershare = (rand(10, 50));
    $randomnumberlike = (rand(10, 50));
    $qu_time = getDatetimeNow();
    $results = mysqli_query($mysqli, "
        UPDATE tbl_quotes SET
         qu_status=1,
         qu_like=$randomnumberlike,
         qu_share=$randomnumbershare,
         qu_favorite=0,
         qu_time='$qu_time' 
            where _quid=$x 
              ORDER BY _quid ASC 
         ");
```

Anyone can please suggest me whats I am missing and how can I fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a `while` loop, instead of a `for` loop, to loop through all the ids of the table, like this:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT _quid FROM tbl_quotes");
while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
    $randomnumbershare = (rand(10,50));
    $randomnumberlike = (rand(10,50));
    $qu_time = getDatetimeNow();
    $results = mysqli_query($mysqli,"UPDATE tbl_quotes SET qu_status=1, qu_like=$randomnumberlike,qu_share=$randomnumbershare,qu_favorite=0, qu_time='$qu_time' where _quid=".$result['_quid']." ORDER BY _quid ASC");
}
```

Comment: hello sir ! Its working fine....but in $results = mysqli_query($mysqli,"UPDATE tbl_quotes SET qu_status=1, qu_like=$randomnumberlike,qu_share=$randomnumbershare,qu_favorite=0, qu_time='$qu_time' where _quid=".$result['_quid']." ORDER BY _quid ASC"); even if I set LIMIT 1,its updating all row....there anything I am missing ? Sorry for my question. Thanks a lot !

Comment: @PremSharma Actually there's no point having `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` clauses in `UPDATE` query, since you're looping through all the ids of the table anyway. If you want to update just one row, then don't use `while` loop in the first place, simply have just one `UPDATE` query and specify the id of the particular row in the `WHERE` clause which you want to update.